# ¿Como optimizar codigo Node js express con Redis?

Tags: nodejs, express, redis

Tengo 2 dudas al momento de aprender redis. He leido varios post y videos pero no resulven mi duda. Tengo lo siguiente:

```
router.get('/' , traeTodosLosProductos)
```

Ésta ruta, me devuelve todos los productos registrados en la base de datos que la tengo en PlanetScale.

El controlador **traeTodosLosProductos**, es el siguiente:

```
import { productosdb } from '../models/productos.models.js'
import { createClient } from 'redis';

const client = createClient();
await client.connect();


const traeTodosLosProductos = async (req,res,next) => {
    try {
        //Buscamos info en redis
        const reply = await client.get('productos');

        //si existe info, terminamos response devolviendo la info
        if(reply) return res.status(200).send(JSON.parse(reply));

        //si llegamos hasta aca, no esta en redis, hacemos la consulta a la base de datos y registramos en caché.
        productosdb.findAll({
            attributes: { exclude: ['id'] }
        }).then(async produc => {
            res.status(200).json(produc);
            await client.set(
                'productos',
                JSON.stringify(produc),
                {
                    EX: 10,
                }
            );
        })   
    } catch (error) {
        return next(error)
    }
}
```

De ésta forma, obtengo la respuesta rápida correctamente. Pero me generan 2 dudas.

1. Como puedo hacer para que se mantenga solamente 1 o 10 minuto en cache y luego se destruya?
2. He visto en algunos casos que lo implementan como middleware, cual es la forma mas correcta u optima de hacerlo? En caso de hacerlo como Middleware, osea algo asi:

**router.get('/' , cache , traeTodosLosProductos)**

Como se implementa?

Comment: 1. le seteas un [EXpire](https://redis.io/commands/set/#options) en segundos, en tu caso sería `10*60` . 2. depende de la aplicación, implementado como middleware express lo asocias a una(s) ruta(s), implementado en el model lo asocias a un(os) modelo(s) ( lo mas sensato suele ser implementarlo en una clase base ); en general middleware para cachear responses (ya cocinadas) y en el model para cachear datos ( esto último sería tu caso )

Comment: al margen, es conveniente usar un patrón de nombres para las keys por ejemplo `productos:all` o algo mas generico `queries:productos:all` ( eso te permitiría luego ir variando el `all` para resultados con filtros usando algun hash o los parametros concatenados )

Comment: @aloMalbarez te agradezco tus comentarios. Pero no pude con la 2 opcion...